# How can i get ap rocess window handle intptr and save the process window to image file?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have the method DrawToBitmap but how do I get the handle of a process window ?
For example notepad.exe

What I want to do is when I start the program if the process(for example notepad.exe) not running yet then start it once it's running get it's window handle and save the window to image file.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Elgato.BaseClasses.UI;
using Elgato;
using Elgato.BaseClasses.Streaming;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;


namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {


        [DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
        private static extern bool PrintWindow(HandleRef hwnd, IntPtr hdcBlt, int nFlags);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        private static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd, ref RECT lpRect);

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        private struct RECT
        {
            public int Left;
            public int Top;
            public int Right;
            public int Bottom;
        }


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();



        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


        }

        public static Image DrawToBitmap(IntPtr handle)
        {
            RECT rect = new RECT();
            GetWindowRect(handle, ref rect);

            Bitmap image = new Bitmap(rect.Right - rect.Left, rect.Bottom - rect.Top);

            using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(image))
            {
                IntPtr hDC = graphics.GetHdc();
                PrintWindow(new HandleRef(graphics, handle), hDC, 0);
                graphics.ReleaseHdc(hDC);
            }

            return image;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Google C# Print Screen.    System.Diagnostics.Process has a Handle member of IntPtr;

Answer (score 2):

To check whether a process exists and get the window handle if it exists, use the following code:

```
    var processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad");
    if (processes.Length > 0)
    {
        var handle = processes[0].MainWindowHandle;
    }
    else
    {
        // Notepad is not started
    }
```

Comment: enhanced my answer